# How to unit test IDisposable?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, garbage-collection, idisposable

I'm working on a piece of library code around `IDisposable`. The managed path (via `using`) is easily testable. I'm wondering about the finalizer though: Is calling [`System.GC.Collect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx) sufficient to force the finalizer to run?

Comment: If you stick to the prescribed pattern for IDisposable, I'm sure that unit testing it is going to be that useful.

Comment: sorry, that should have been "I'm not sure that unit testing it is going to be that useful...

Comment: @Mitch: implementing IDisposable correctly, so that managed and unmanaged resources are disposed of at the right moment is not trivial. As the library code in question is responsible for exactly that I don't see a point in _not_ testing that ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17014062/339384

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the GC.Collect() call is asynchronous, you would also need to call this:

```
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: I think the GC.Collect() itself is synchronous (i.e. it will have freed any memory it can by the time it returns) but the finalizers themselves run separately. I could be entirely wrong though...

Comment: I'm doing both now and the test passed every time. That is, called the correct extension point from the finalizer.

Comment: Note to self: also check that the initialisation code of the class in question doesn't "root" the object somewhere.

Comment: @EricBurcham: an example where I use that is here: https://github.com/daszat/zetbox/blob/master/Tests/DisposableMockTemplate.cs

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I called `GC.Collect()` and then `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` and at no point is `disposing` ever `false`

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at [Dispose, Finalization, and Resource Management](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae)
 its the best reference on the subject I know of. Using their pattern:

```
~ComplexCleanupBase()
{
    Dispose(false);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
   if (!disposed)
   {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // dispose-only, i.e. non-finalizable logic
        }

        // new shared cleanup logic
        disposed = true;
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

You wind up with dead simple Finalizer/Dispose() methods and a testable Dispose(bool). No need to force Finalization or anything using the GC class.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing it quite like that. It's only a slight adaptation of what's recommended in the MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Could you mock out an `IDisposable` interface and expect a call to `Dispose`?  That would at least let you see when the object is actually disposed.

Comment: Setting a breakpoint is sufficient to discover that. I'm testing the Dispose()'s implementation though, not whether it's called.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would lean towards making Finalize() call another method, and test that the other method does what you want.  You wouldn't get 100% code coverage, but at least you'd know that the method releases the object's resources properly.